# how to get this config value from app.config?

Tags: c#

My friend has the following app.config. He wants to get the value of `address`. how to do it?

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
...
           <client>
            <endpoint address="http://ldo:8080/LLService" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ILLService" contract="LLServiceReference.ILLService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_ILLService">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="ggldoe@mail.com" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`<system.serviceModel>` documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354.aspx).

You should:

1. Call the `ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup` method
2. Choose an endpoint from the `serviceModelSectionGroup.Client.Endpoints` collection. Presumably you want to look at a specific contract.
3. Look at that endpoint's `Address` property

Comment: what's the value we should pass into the ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup method?

Comment: It's likely to come from `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`

Answer (score 9):

try this to Get first endpoint

```
Configuration configuration =    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModelSectionGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(configuration);
ClientSection clientSection = serviceModelSectionGroup.Client;
var el = clientSection.Endpoints[0];
return el.Address.ToString();
```