# how to read endpoint address value from app.config

Tags: c#, api

I have `asp.net web application` and have the following in my `app.config` file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Test" />
    <binding name="Test1">
      <security mode="Test" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://test:90001"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Test"
    contract="Test" name="HTTP_Port" />
     </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How i can `get/read endpoint address` value?

I have come accross the this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214385/how-to-get-this-config-value-from-app-config) but it is not working for me asking for exe file path. Not sure which exe path file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read WCF service endpoint address by name from web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572890/read-wcf-service-endpoint-address-by-name-from-web-config)

Answer (score 2):

```
     var serviceModel = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None));
        var endpoints = serviceModel.Client.Endpoints;
        foreach (ChannelEndpointElement e in endpoints)
        {
            if (e.Name == "HTTP_Port")
            Console.WriteLine(e.Address);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

To read endpoints from appconfig you need to add reference of System.ServiceModel.Configuration and use GetSectionGroup method which return the serviceModel group and you can access all the endpoints in that section,if you just need the one you can access specific with the endpoint name.

Also in the appconfig you provided the port is invalid, I got and error while reading the url with that port I assume you just added that as an example.

Comment: Same error " exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe." i am getting.Followed exactly what you said.

Comment: @simbada can you add the stack details of error please..!